# Guzzle not reading passed header array

Tags: php, guzzle

I am sure this is something simple, but I cannot figure out what I have wrong in my Guzzle request.  It seems when passing an array of values, the client is not reading my array.  If I hard code the values in the request, it works.

```
$options = [
    'verify' => false,
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd',
    'http_errors' => false
];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$httpResultArray = $client->request('GET', 'https://someplace.com', [
    'headers' => $options
]);
```

Comment: Solved.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to having brackets around the passed array ($options) in the request.  It was creating a nested array.

```
$options = [
    'verify' => false,
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . 'abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd',
    'http_errors' => false
];

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$httpResultArray = $client->request('GET', 'https://someplace.com',$options);
```